# Converting MailGun cUrl to Coldfusion

Tags: curl, coldfusion-9, mailgun

I'm attempting to perform actions on a Mailgun mailing list using Coldfusion.

Mailgun have supplied the following cUrl:

```
curl -s --user 'api:key-xxxMyAPIkeyxxx' -G \
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/myList@myDomain.mailgun.org/members
```

I can get a good response by simply entering

```
https://api:key-xxxmyAPIkeyxxx@api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/myList@myDomain.mailgun.org/members
```

But I've had no luck converting this into a CFHTTP call:

```
<cfhttp url="https://api:key-xxxmyAPIkey@api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/myList@myDomain.mailgun.org/members" method="GET" result="resultName">
```

```
<cfdump var="#resultName#">
```

This returns a whole load of errors:

> object
>   ErrorDetail [string]
>   Mimetype [string]   application/json
>   Statuscode [string] 401 Unauthorized
>   Filecontent [object]
>   object [empty]
>   Responseheader [object] 
>   object
>   Connection [string] close
>   Content-Length [number] 0
>   Date [string]   Mon, 10 Aug 2015 16:46:22 GMT
>   Explanation [string]    Unauthorized
>   Content-Type [string]   application/json
>   Http_Version [string]   HTTP/1.1
>   Www-Authenticate [string]   Basic realm="MG API"
>   Server [string] nginx/1.7.9
>   Status_Code [number]    401
>   Text [boolean]  false
>   Charset [string]
>   Header [string] HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Content-Type: application/json Connection: close Date: Mon, 10 Aug 2015 16:46:22 GMT Www-Authenticate: Basic realm="MG API" Content-Length: 0 Server: nginx/1.7.9

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Mailgun API](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-intro.html#authentication) says basic authentication is used.  Try supplying the credentials via the [`username` and `password` attributes](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfhttp) instead of the URL:

```
<cfhttp url="https://api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/myList@myDomain.mailgun.org/members" 
      method="GET" 
      username="api" 
      password="key-xxxYourAPIKeyxxx"
      result="resultName" />
```